# virtual address assignment in C and linux 

Tags: c, linux

In the program given below virtual address for both process is same. I understood the reason for global variables but could not understand for local variables.

**how is virtual addresses assigned to local variables before running?**

```
int main()
{
  int a;
  if (fork() == 0)
  { 
     a = a + 5; 
    printf(“%d,%d\n”, a, &a); 
  }
  else 
  { 
     a = a –5;
    printf(“%d, %d\n”, a, &a); 
   } 
}
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack

Comment: Incidentally, use `%p` rather than `%d` for pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While compiling, the compiler decides to use either the stack or a register for local variables. In this case, the stack.

It also decides where in the (virtual) address space to place the stack.

So for both processes the stack starts in the same (virtual) address. And since the flow of this specific program is rather deterministic, the stack frames look exactly the same for both processes, resulting in the same offset in the stack for 'a'.

Comment: It's even simpler than this. `a`'s lifetime began *before* the `fork`, so it's not only a consequence of implementation details, but actually *required*, that `a` have the same address in both. Actually I wonder if this is something some optimizing compilers might get wrong in certain cases, by performing "lazy" allocation of stack variables (perhaps after a VLA is allocated that has different sizes in the child and parent) when the variable "should have" existed before the `fork` and thus must have the same address in both parent and child...

Answer (score 3):

Virtual addresses are... virtual. That means a same virtual address from two different processes (like a parent process and its child process) points to two different physical addresses.

Comment: but when a program is compiled how and why virtual addresses are given to local variables? they are needed only when function is called right?

Comment: local variables are stored in the stack and will be removed when they are no longer needed

Comment: Local variables only get an address at runtime; the compiler doesn't give them an "address", but an "offset" relative to the stack pointer (i.e. something like 'this variable is 16 bytes away from the top of the stack"). In your case, the stackpointer will be the same in both processes after the fork(), so after applying the same offset in both processes you still get the same address.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever the address of `a` was before the fork, it must surely be the same after the fork, so it necessarily is the same in the two processes, since their addresses for `a` are both equal to the same thing. In most implementations, the address of `a` is derived by adding an offset (determined by the compiler) to the content of the stack pointer. The content of the stack pointer is duplicated by fork.